# Progress Dialog not showing up in AsyncTask

Tags: java, android, listview, android-asynctask, dialog

I have an Android application with an AsyncTask which is responsible for downloading a file from the internet. This AsyncTask is executed when clicking on an item in a Listview. So I have a custom adapter and in the OnItemClickListener of the Listview, I start the download and execute the AsyncTask.

Now, my adapter contains the following code to start the AsyncTask named FileDownloader:

```
@Override
public void onClick(View view) {
     try {
         FileDownloader fd = new FileDownloader(activity);
         // some irrelevant code here
         String filepath = fd.execute("http://myurl.com/img.png", PDFFileName, GameHistoryAdapter.this.gameInfo.toString()).get();
     }
     catch(Exception e) { e.printStackTrace(); }
}
```

Activity is a private field that is passed to the adapter in the constructor of the adapter:

```
public GameHistoryAdapter(Activity a, int selectedIndex) {
    this.activity = a;
}
```

The FileDownloader class contains an OnPreExecute method where I want to show the progress dialog on the activity:

```
@Override
protected void onPreExecute() {
    super.onPreExecute();

    dialog = new ProgressDialog(activity);
    dialog.setMessage("Downloading...");
    dialog.setIndeterminate(true);
    dialog.setCancelable(true);
    dialog.show();
}
```

But whatever I try, the dialog does not appear. When I create an alert dialog in the OnPostExecute method of the AsyncTask, the dialog will show.

```
@Override
protected void onPostExecute(String res)
{
    super.onPostExecute(res);
    dialog.hide();

    new AlertDialog.Builder(activity)
            .setTitle(activity.getString(R.string.save_pdf_title_text))
            .setMessage(activity.getString(R.string.save_pdf_text) + PDFFileName)
            .setPositiveButton(activity.getString(R.string.close_text), null)
            .setIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_info)
            .show();
}
```

Does anyone know why the dialog is not appearing on my activity?

Comment: initialise dialog in the constructor of AsyncTask..and in onPreExecute only write dialog.show();

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Does anyone know why the dialog is not appearing on my activity?

Yes, the following line of code...

```
String filepath = fd.execute("http://myurl.com/img.png", PDFFileName, GameHistoryAdapter.this.gameInfo.toString()).get();
```

Don't *EVER* use the `get()` method of `AsyncTask`. It will block the main / UI thread and makes the whole point of an `AsyncTask` redundant. In other words `get()` turns it into a synchronous process instead of an asynchronous one.

The fact you can show a dialog in `onPostExecute(...)` is simply because it will be called after the blocking call to `get()` has returned. This means the main / UI thread will no longer be frozen (blocked) and UI updates can be made once again.

Remove `get()` from your call to `execute(...)` and instead just use...

```
fd.execute("http://myurl.com/img.png", PDFFileName, GameHistoryAdapter.this.gameInfo.toString());
```

...then in your `onPostExecute(...)` method set you `filepath` variable to what it should be.

I don't know who added the `get()` method to `AsyncTask` but if I ever find them I'll have some serious words to say. It has little or no use and causes a lot of people a lot of confusion.

Comment: Great answer! Removing the get method did it for me. I didn't know that the get was making the request synchronous so this explained a lot. The addition of the get method to AsyncTask is indeed strange.

Comment: @Devos50 : Yep, I've seen quite a few questions like yours here on Stack Overflow and I've never worked out a really good use for the `get()` method. I wish they'd deprecate it or even better make it obsolete and remove it altogether. Anyway, glad to help.

Comment: Valid points indeed, but I have many situations where `AsyncTask`'s `get()` is _inevitable_. E.g.: I need to show a `ProgressDialog` **_until all network download is completed_**, then dismiss it and continue with refreshed UI. The download time is not known, so I cannot use the `get(time)` variant. Simply put, the UI *has to wait* and the only way to do that seems to be with `get()`. Are there (simpler) alternatives?

Comment: BTW - I too am just unable to show a `ProgressDialog` in `AsyncTask`, like Devos50. I understand why, but sadly, `get()` is the only thing that seems to hold my app together.